# How can I call multiple activities inside a flow?

Tags: ipaf, paceautomationframework

How can I call multiple activities inside a flow using PAF in my system?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can call multiple Activities inside a flow using `<call activity="act_id" xml=""/>`

Eg:

```
<flows>
      <flow id="test_flow" name="my_first_test_flow" desc="Testing Multiple Activities in one flow" excelPath="./data/test1.xlsx">
             <call activity="activity1" xml="./sample_xml/activity_Multiflow.xml" />
             <call activity="activity2" xml="./sample_xml/activity_Multiflow.xml" />
             <call activity="activity3" xml="./sample_xml/activity_Multiflow.xml" />

      </flow>
</flows>
```